# How to use  for forced unwrap in Swift 5.0 / Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to be able to use  instead of ! for forced unwraps in Swift code. 
If this was C++ I might try using #define or something like that, but I am not sure how this could be accomplished.

I can't just globally replace ! with , as it's used for not, and for declaring force unwrap variables, and maybe some other stuff

Would it be easier with some sort of Xcode macro, or a plugin?

Comment: I love this idea. It stands out visually, while being short and not cluttering code, and it's hard to type which discourage use. Great idea!

Comment: While this is a cool idea, note that you'll quickly run into places where a custom `` operator or method cannot be used in place of postfix `!`, as the latter has a bunch of special language support. For example `x!` can be treated as an lvalue, allowing for code like this `var x: Int? = 0; x! += 1`. The ability to be treated as an lvalue also extends into optional chains, e.g `x!.y += 1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments & Matt's answer, the  character is not available to be an operator, so if you specifically want to use it, then you can do it with an extension as seen here.

```
extension Optional {
    var : Wrapped {
        return self!
    }
}

var string: String? = "42"
print(string.) // 42

var number: Int? = nil
print(number.) // Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This extension makes use of the `Optional` type, so it can be used with any data type that conforms to Optional.

However, if you want to the postfix route, then the following offers an option:

```
postfix operator ☠
extension Optional {
    postfix static func ☠(optional: Optional<Wrapped>) -> Wrapped {
        return optional!
    }
}

var bad: String?
print(bad☠)
```

Sadly, the skull & crossbones do not show as well here as they do in Xcode.

[image]

On a serious note for OP, if you wish to enforce usage of this within a team, I would recommend a tool such as swiftlint, where you can modify the rules around force unwrapping to require some .

Comment: Not a custom postfix operator?

Comment: @matt I tried, but  is not an acceptable character per Swift guidelines to be an operator :(

Comment: What? Outrageous!

Comment: Tell me about it! I tried a few others (fire, explosions, ambulance but no joy...)

Comment: @matt Here's a handy list of all of the allowable operator symbols: https://gist.github.com/natecook1000/c5fb2b8cd0967f53770e The best fit for this case is❗, IMO

Comment: Thanks guys. I am going to probably make my students use this, as a fun reinforcing of hey don't do it.

Comment: `unsafelyUnwrapped` isn't the same as `!` in a release/optimized build.  Why not just do `return self!`

Comment: Yup, as @vacawama says, in an optimised build, `unsafelyUnwrapped` will assume that the optional is non-nil, yielding undefined behaviour if it is `nil`. `!` on the other hand always performs a check for `nil`, and is guaranteed to crash on encountering `nil`.

Comment: This would also be a fun way to teach operators. There's a whole little lecture hidden in this question.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately you can't use the  character as a postfix operator like `!`, but here's an alternative:

```
postfix operator ⏰
extension Optional {
    postfix public static func ⏰(a: Optional<Wrapped>) -> Wrapped {
        return a!
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var crashme : String? // nil
print(crashme⏰) // crash
```

I like this alternative symbol since it implies a ticking time bomb, which is just what an IUO is. Or maybe it implies Hey wake up!

Comment: @Cœur Well, no. The whole problem is that most of those are not allowed as operator characters (and especially not operator _first_ characters). That's what https://gist.github.com/natecook1000/c5fb2b8cd0967f53770e is all about (not to mention the official docs).